# Why does this acquire and release memory fence not give a consistent value?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, memory-barriers

im just exploring the use of acquire and release memory fences and  dont understand why i get the value output to zero sometimes and not the value of 2 all the time

I ran the program a number of times , and assumed the atomic store before the release barrier and the atomic load after the acquire barrier would ensure the values always would synchronise

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int>x;



void write()
{


    x.store(2,std::memory_order_relaxed);

    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);



}

void read()
{

    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

    // THIS DOES NOT GIVE THE EXPECTED VALUE OF 2 SOMETIMES
    std::cout<<x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)<<std::endl; 

}

int main()
{

std::thread t1(write);
std::thread t2(read);
t1.join();
t2.join();
return 0;
}
```

the atomic varible x gives a value of 0 sometimes

Comment: This is a kind of "I didn't expect that result Q". Please explain in your Q why you expect that exact result: what are your assumptions, your reasoning, your guesses...

Comment: Are you imagining that if the read thread happens to get scheduled first, the thread fence operation causes that thread to halt and wait for the write thread? It might help if you explain what you think the `atomic_thread_fence` operation does.

Comment: thanks for your responses, i mistakenly assumed  that the fences did synchronisations on the same variables before and after them,

Comment: @AfzelAdam Fences and relaxed operations are among the most complex, most difficult to intuitively get and most subtle concept to correctly specify in a program language standard. You probably want rather want to use semaphores (or even Windows events)

Comment: @curiousguy  using x.store( "value" ,std::memory_order_release);  x.load(std::memory_order_acquire); pairs  seems a lot simpler to understand , perhaps this is the most recommended when using atomics?

Comment: @AfzelAdam Store release and load acquire are easy to use to publish data and consume that data when the consuming threads can deal with the data being not available yet, and don't have to wait for it.

Comment: Was your Q specifically about an old version of the C++ std?

Comment: Oh was just about c++ 11 and up,, the memory fences looked interesting and challenging , but i guess for algorithms  perhaps some other mechnaisms for concurrency are more suitable and intuitative

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of fences. Fences only enforce a certain ordering of memory operations for the compiler and processor in a single thread of execution. Your acquire fence will not magically make the thread wait until the óther thread performs the release.

Some literature will describe that a release operation in one thread "synchronizes with" a subsequent acquire operation in another thread. The key to this is that the acquire action is a subsequent action (i.e. the acquire is ordered "after" the release). If the release action is ordered after your acquire action, then there is no synchronizes-with relation between the write and read operations.

The reason why your code doesn't consistently return what you're expecting is because the thread interleavings sometimes order the write before the read, sometimes the read before the write.

If you want to guarantee that thread `t2` reads the value `2` that thread `t1` publishes, you're going to have to force `t2` to wait for the publish to happen. The textbook example almost invariably uses a guard variable that notifies `t2` that the data is ready to be consumed.

I recommend you read a very well-written blog post about release and acquire semantics and the synchronizes-with relation at Preshing on Programming's [The Synchronizes-With Relation](https://preshing.com/20130823/the-synchronizes-with-relation/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, im assuming that when reading 
after the acquire fence you keep checking using a loop or if condition

im guessing something like this?

    void read()
    {

        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)==2)
        
            std::cout<<x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

    }

Comment: Not quite. If you're only concerned with the value of x becoming 2, you might as well just use relaxed semantics. The whole purpose of release is to make sure that stores "above" the fence cannot be reordered with stores "below" the fence. Likewise, acquire semantics makes sure that loads above the fence cannot be reordered with loads below the fence. In your example, you might as well just use relaxed semantics since you're only concerned with inter-thread visibility (i.e. that `t2` eventually sees the `t1`'s write to `x`.

Comment: @AfzelAdam Why would you even want to use (anonymous) fence operations (those that don't specifically apply to one designated atomic object) when you only care about one atomic object? Why do you use relaxed stores and loads if you want to make results visible? Just use release stores and acquire loads and drop the fence.

Comment: @Eric Is the above/below terminology standard?

Comment: @curiousguy, I don't know if it's standard terminology but from a pedagogical perspective it illustrates the idea since we generally organize sequences of instructions top-down. The C++ standard seems to prefer the terms before and after in its definition of "sequenced-before".

Also, a comment on your comment. I don't think that store-release and load-acquire are necessary. Relaxed loads and stores and no barriers should work just fine if the OP wants the write to become visible in `t2`'s read, right?

Comment: @Eric Exactly, for a single atomic object barriers are not necessary. Information should be propagated extremely quickly in practice. On Intel stores are never reordered and you can't make the availability of changes to global memory any faster. On CPU that do reorder stores, they have no reason to artificial keep a store in the queue as it consumes resources; they would have a reason to keep a store queued only if it's overwritten by a more recent store, like a counter in a loop. Either way, mode changes (caused by syscalls or interrupts) will force a drain on queued stores.

Comment: Regardless of the underlying architecture's memory model, relaxed loads and stores in this case would give an optimizing compiler more freedom to reorder instructions, even if there is no practical difference between a relaxed store and a release store on TSO.

Comment: @curiousguy just a simple example, wasnt aware of the fact that fences only order and do not synchronise, do release stores and acquired loads offer better performance than fences ?

Comment: @eric , many thanks for your feedback, was just curious about Reads, are they guranteed not be reordered  above and below a  Release fence.. and Writes cannot be reordered above and below an Acquire fence ?

Comment: @AfzelAdam An acquire (release) fence applies to **all previous (following) relaxed operations** that didn't already had acquire (release) semantics. It "retroactively" adds acquire to previous reading operations, except that the only the code after the fences is protected. It's inherently more general and powerful than an acquire read to it cannot be cheaper. About the real cost, the answer is CPU specific. BTW the fence in your comment above "`std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); if (x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)==2) `" doesn't protect the load, only previous loads.

Comment: @AfzelAdam, loads and stores "above" a release fence are not allowed to be reordered with stores "below" the release fence. Likewise, loads "above" an acquire fence are not allowed to be reordered with loads and stores "below" the acquire fence.

Comment: @Eric That's only true for memory access that isn't inherently a race condition. An access to an normal object that is done before a fence can be combined with one after a fence: `n=1; AR_OP; n++;` [where `n` is a global `int` and AR_OP is either an acquire or release fence, an atomic operation that does acquire or release (or both)] can be compiled as `AR_OP; n=2;` because there is no way for other threads to observe the non atomic `n`. The CPU can't do that stuff, the compiler can. C++ is a high level language and not specified in term of sequential compilation of individual statements.

Comment: A way to understand a pure fence is a division of an atomic operation into a more relaxed operation and an anti-relaxation (re-enforcement?). The only strong need for a fence is when you have existing atomic operations that are relaxed and that you can't change, but in general you should probably always give the operation proper ack/rel semantics. (The only exception is when you want to micro-optimize atomics which is OK but not for beginners.)

Comment: @curiousguy, is this stated somewhere in the C++ standard? Trying to observe such an optimization with the example you gave without success.

Comment: @Eric Which compiler are you using? GCC doesn't have the ability to optimize around atomic ops as they are "opaque". And no, the std doesn't usually explain how to optimize C++ programs.

Comment: @curiousguy, yes I am using gcc. And obviously, it's not the standard's job to explain how to optimize programs. :) What I meant was does the standard state somewhere (directly or indirectly) that accesses to a non-atomic before a fence can be combined with accesses after a fence? It seems counter-intuitive to be able to optimize away side-effects before a release barrier/operation.

Comment: @Eric GCC will not even optimize the most obvious cases of redundant atomic operations like increment followed by a decrement (which can be produced f.ex. by the creation of a temporary copy of a `shared_ptr` or returning a copy of local object that uses refcounting if "copy elision" or rather "object fusion" can't be applied). There is a myth (even propagated by std committee members apparently) that sequence of obviously redundant atomic ops can't be simplified, fused, and optimized. (Only volatile operations can't be simplified and optimized, by definition of volatile.)

Comment: The std doesn't list possible program optimization; it doesn't say that redundant integer operations can be fused and simplified and nobody questions that a compiler can simplified f.ex. `x+a-a` to `x` (for native types not user defined overloaded operators obv.). Operations can be combined simply **because the intermediate results aren't observable** by any normal programmatic way, inside the program (ie anything that doesn't involve ptrace, a debugger, direct RAM access...). All the compiler needs to determine is what can be observed... which in general isn't possible (halting problem).

Comment: A modification **M1** to a normal object before a release operation ("anonymous" fence or store-release) can be combined to another **M2** after it, moving **M1** after the fence and just before **M2** to combine them, provided the object isn't accessed in that thread between **M1** and **M2** (by name or by an alias), simply because no program can observe that change: `extern int x; x=1; a.store(1); x++;` can be compiled to `a.store(1); x=2;` because no program can measure `x` "during" an atomic operation. The same applies for reads of a global object, and for acquire operations.

Comment: What you may have had in mind with your "intuition tells me no way the fusion of operations is OK" comment is `x=1; L.unlock(); stuff(); L.lock(); ++x;` where there is no possible fusion of operation as: 1) `x` must be 1 before the unlock operation (which is a release operation) 2) `x` doesn't have to be 1 after the lock operation (which is an acquire operation).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you misuse the fence. You are trying to use it as a mutex, right? If you expect the code to output 2 always, you just think that the `load` operation would never be executed before the `save` one. But that is not what memory fence does, that is what the synchronization primitives do.

The fences are much trickier and they just don't allow compiler/processor to reorder certain types of commands within one thread. At the end of the day the order of execution of two separate threads is undefined.

Comment: "_But that is not what memory fence does, that is what the synchronization primitives do._" No, **that's what putting stuff in sequence, separated either by `;` for instructions or `,` for expression, in one function, does**. The "synchronization primitives" like mutexes do serialization of a operations started by concurrent threads. They are used when a well defined ordering is needed **and any order is acceptable**.

Comment: "You are trying to use it as a mutex, right?" I think here a condition variable is more suitable.

Comment: @xskxzr, have you seen a condition variable without a mutex?

Comment: @curiousguy, please clarify the statement "that's what putting stuff in sequence, separated either by ; for instructions or , for expression, in one function, does".

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Here one precise function needs to be executed before another one; you don't need just any order, but one order. The way to do it is to call these functions in sequence. Threads are irrelevant.

Comment: @curiousguy This very simplified code is written by a person who studies concurrency. Sequencial execution of the functions is not regarded as a solution, I guess...

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov It's so "simplified" that only the meaningless parts are kept. It's a non-solution "solution". Concurrent execution means that the expected data may or may not be available when it is wanted; then what should happen? We don't know. Sequential execution is the simplest obviously correct solution. If the consuming code must run in another thread, then a signaling protocol is necessary. We don't have enough information to evaluate signaling designs.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons is simple: your fences accomplish exactly nothing and cannot have any use here anyway because **there is no write that the fence would make visible (on the release side) to the acquiring side**.

The simple answer is that the reading thread can run first and obviously will not see any write if it does.

The longer answer is that **when your code has a race**, as any code that uses either mutexes or atomics in a non trivial way, **it must be prepared for any race outcome!** So you has to make sure that not reading the value written by a write will not break your code.

ADDITIONAL EXPLANATION

A way to explain rel/ack semantics is:

- release means "**I have accomplished something**" and I set that atomic object to some value to publish that claim;
- acquire means "**have you accomplished something?**" and I read that atomic object to see if it contains the claim.

So release before you have accomplished anything is meaningless and an acquire that throws away the information containing the claim, as in `(void)x.load(memory_order_acquire)` is generally meaningless as there is no knowledge (in general) of what was acquired, which is to say of what was accomplished. (The exception to that rule is when a thread had relaxed loads or RMW operations.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, so like before release have something set, and after acquire keep checking till i have the right or relevant value.

Comment: @AfzelAdam Yes almost all real world code makes a test on the result of a read of an atomic variable before going further; the most widely used acquire operation in C++ is in `shared_ptr` where it is needed in the refcount decrement function as it observes the completion of all other decrements for all threads that called `reset` (or equivalently destroyed the `shared_ptr` instance).